# Partial fractions: case when in the denominator a factor occurs with N multiplicity

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

Suppose we have:

$$\int \frac{3x^3-4x^2-3x+2}{x^2(x+1)(x-1)} ~dx$$

now why do we have to do this with the term with multiplicity greater than $1$?

why the $x^2$ term becomes a sum:

$$\frac{A}{x} +\frac{B}{x^2}+ \frac{C}{(x+1)}+ \frac{D}{(x-1)}$$

Comment: If that term were not there, then adding those fractions would not give an $x^2$ in the denominator. When you add fractions, you can take as common denominator the product of all denominators. There could be some cancelations, which can decrease some apparent multiplicity, but never increase it.

Comment: As an alternative to brute force partial fractions, consider $$3x^3-4x^2-3x+2= 3x^2(x-1)-2x^2-2(x^2-1)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do partial fraction, you need to check the highest power on the numerator is strictly less than the highest power on the denominator. So for $x^2$ term in the denominator, in general, the numerator has to be at least 1 order less, hence it is linear $ax+b$, we have

$$\frac{ax+b}{x^2}=\frac a x+\frac b{x^2}$$

Comment: Read my first sentence. @SirMrpirateroberts

Comment: Correct, if the OP has numerator's highest power $\ge$ the highest power of the denominator, then you need to do the long division first. Next, for the remainder part, do the partial fraction. @SirMrpirateroberts

Comment: why is it that partial fractions only work for the power of the numerator is less than that of the denominator

Comment: think the connection between long division and partial fraction, then you can figure out the reason @SirMrpirateroberts

Comment: Thanks, finally I want to clarify what happens when we have a term in the denominator in the form $(x^2+a)$ becomes :                                            $$\frac{Cx+D}{x^2+1}$$???

Comment: correct @SirMrpirateroberts

Comment: but why that happens?

Comment: no cancelation occurs?

Comment: If your denominator is a quadratic that can't be reduced, like $x^2+1$, then you can either (a) switch to the complex numbers where it can be reduced, or (b) separate it into $\frac{Cx}{x^2+1} + \frac{D}{x^2+1}$, noting that the first term is susceptible to a substitution of $u = x^2 + 1$ and the second is the derivative of an inverse tangent function.